# Location directive not working

Tags: nginx, web-server, virtualhost, http-status-code-404

For my NGINX server I have a virtual server set up just to dish out static content. At the moment I'm trying to set it up so that images have an expiry date. However, when I create a location directive for this, everything just results in a 404.

My configuration right now is looking like this:

**/srv/www/static.conf**

```
server {
    listen                          80;
    server_name                     static.*.*;

    location / {
            root                    /srv/www/static;
            deny                    all;
    }

    location /images {
            expires                 1y;
            log_not_found           off;
            root                    /srv/www/static/images;
    }
}
```

*Note, this file is included from /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, inside a http directive*

I'm trying to access the image, at, let's say... `static.example.com/images/screenshots/something.png`. Sure enough, the image also exists at `/srv/www/static/images/screenshots/something.png`. However, going to said address does not work and simply tells me **404 Not Found**.

However, if I remove `location /images` and change `location /` to the following...

```
location / {
    root /srv/www/static;
}
```

It works! What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your configuration is following nginx configuration [pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) You should read it before configuring nginx.

To answer your question, you should not define `root` in location, define it once and the location tag will automatically let you assign access to specific directories.

Also instead of defining custom root for images directory, use `try_files`. The `$uri` will map `/images/` directory with `/static/images/`.

Try this configuration:

```
server {
    listen                          80;
    server_name                     static.*.*;
    root                            /srv/www;

    location /static/ {
            deny                    all;
    }

    location /images/ {
            expires                 1y;
            log_not_found           off;
            autoindex               off;
            try_files $uri static/images$uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have read the pitfalls, but I guess my memory failed me. This works, though I edited it slightly for my purposes.

Comment: Yeah I re-read parts of it from time to time myself, there's a reason it has a separate wiki page for it ;)

Comment: If defining `root` inside `location` is bad practice, how come they're doning it themselves in [docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)? (see where it says "*it is better to use the root directive instead*") **CORRECTION**: okay, it seems that what's wrong is defining the primary root in a location, not just any root